# Transpiled TS import .default is undefined, cannot test google cloud functions locally? Is this cloud functions issue or TS config issue?

Tags: javascript, typescript, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I have a super simple test cloud function in typescript locally

```
import { HttpFunction } from '@google-cloud/functions-framework'
import { Request, Response } from 'express'

export const testFuncHandler: HttpFunction = async (req: Request, res: Response): Promise<void> => {
  const message = 'hello world'
  res.status(200).send(message)
}
```

that compiles into something like this in index.js

```
"use strict";
var __importDefault = (this && this.__importDefault) || function (mod) {
    return (mod && mod.__esModule) ? mod : { "default": mod };
};
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
const functions_framework_1 = __importDefault(require("@google-cloud/functions-framework"));
const testFuncHandler_1 = require("./http/testFuncHandler");
functions_framework_1.default.http('testFuncHandler', testFuncHandler_1.testFuncHandler);
//# sourceMappingURL=index.js.map
```

When I run `yarn functions-framework --target=testFuncHandler`, things error out because `functions_framework_1.default` is undefined. However, if I just manually remove the `.default` and instead just do `functions_framework_1.http('testFuncHandler', testFuncHandler_1.testFuncHandler);` I am actually able to test the cloud function locally.

Is this an issue with google cloud? Or my ts config? How am I supposed to proceed when the compiled code is causing issues??

EDIT here is my TS config

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "target": "es2020"
  },
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "include": ["src"]
}
```

Comment: You might want to edit the question to actually show the contents of your tsconfig if you want feedback on how to fix it.

Comment: Just added the TS config

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27293